# Reg : Make sure the Alarm is persistent after we force kill the application

Tags: android, notifications, storage, alarmmanager, alarm

I have application which will depends on alarm , I have created an alarm it runs perfectly at same time every day.

ISSUE: If the my application is killed the alarm goes off.

I need solution to keep the alarm still persist even my application is closed.

I am asking because my application is very simple UI interface which will set alarm at particular time and at that time it does specified task that all

but FIRST how can i make alarm persist , similar to OUR android default ALARM apps ..

After setting the alarm in the android , even after we kill the default ALARM apps still we can see small ALARM icon on the top notifications and the alarm will trigger next day.

Can we do it for our own application.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MusicPlayActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, selectedFile.getPath());

pendingIndent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

// adding the hour and minutes to the calendar
firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourSelected);
firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesSelected);
firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            firingCal.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            pendingIndent);
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I think you may have to show some of your code, and to be more specific. For instance, what have you tried?

Comment: Sure next Time dont use such words

Comment: it is alarm and it set off a task at specified time.